# In angular2 how to retain html5 control values after a manual browser refresh/ reload?

Tags: angular

I am trying out angular2 app. When I reload/ refresh the browser, I lose the values in the html5 control. For example, if I have certain value in a text box, when I refresh the page manually, I lose the value. Is there any method to retain the value?

Thanks,

Kd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everytime you change a model persist it in localstorage and then onInit read it back.

The localstorage for angular 2:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage

just inject it to your component and module

```
import { LocalStorageService, LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

// Create config options (see ILocalStorageServiceConfigOptions) for deets:
let localStorageServiceConfig = {
   prefix: 'my-app',
    storageType: 'sessionStorage'
};

// Use the provider:
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ..
    ],
    declarations: [
        ..
    ],
    providers: [
        LocalStorageService,
        {
            provide: LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG, useValue: localStorageServiceConfig
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@Component({
    // ...    
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor (
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) {
        // YAY!
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have example of localstorage? Any links to documentation will help. Thanks!